# Sending the correct values to an email through AJAX

Tags: html, ajax, email, request

When clicking on the button, i'll receive an email with the text "field1" and "field2". It should instead represent the value entered in num1 and num2. I'm pretty sure that the problem lies in the following line, but im not sure how to solve this issue:`xhttp.send("num1=field1&num2=field2");`

```js
function calculate() {
  var field1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  var field2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;

  var result = parseFloat(field1) * parseFloat(field2) - (995 * parseFloat(field1));

  if (!isNaN(result)) {
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Savings in total: €" + result + ".00 excl. VAT";
  }


  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {}
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "php/calcA.php", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send("num1=field1&num2=field2");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You send a string and not variables.

Instead of doing :

```
xhttp.send("num1=field1&num2=field2");
```

Do :

```
xhttp.send("num1="+field1+"&num2="+field2);
```

Comment: You are a digital lifesaver. Thanks :-)

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to select as best answer :)